# How to unit test newrelic go agent

Tags: go, newrelic

I am new to golang and newrelic.

as part of my work i am migrating newrelic go agent to V3 Version.

But I am facing the problem in the below situation.

while doing unit testing
existing go agent
1.we are able to fake application and fake newrelic transcation.
2.so we were able to count the number of calls to StartSegmentNow

but with the new version of the go agent

1. I am unable to fake the transaction so I can't count on the StartSegment
2. how to mock the newrelic go agent for unit-testing?
   could you please help me with how can I unit test the newrelic transaction using golang

Comment: The question is "why are you unable to fake the transaction?" I think, answering it properly will move you forward at least halfway.

Comment: I want to unit test the application. whenever HTTP calls happened I want to unit test that it will create the no. of transactions based on my HTTP calls. better way to put my question is how can i mock the newrelic goagent for testing

Comment: @SoumyaSriram you should probably wrap the newrelic into another object that you can mock yourself. 
You can also leverage newrelic.Config to disable the integration https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3@v3.13.0/newrelic#Config.Enabled